# how to fix jupyter notebook read-only

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, jupyter, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm creating another environment with Anaconda on WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux).
- Ubuntu , conda 4.5.12, python3.6

I've actually copied windows files stored in /mnt/c/ to wsl home directory.

And I tried to use them in jupyter notebook, it always comes with "read-only" file and am not even able to create a new python file in jupyter notebook.

I've checked on permission on those files:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     599226 Jan 22 21:14 test.ipynb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     706198 Jan 22 21:14 test2.ipynb
```

Suppose it says I can write them.
Then I went through jupyter permission as well:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myname myname      240 Jan 23 18:25 jupyter
```

So I guess I can fully handle jupyter notebook too.

Is there anything I should look into to solve this problem?
Thanks much!

Comment: Use `chmod` to change permission.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was copying the notebook to the server under the root, and later trying to use it from under another account. Copying/creating the file from the same acc that is used to run the file is the key to success )